# Button Image - Image Stack on top of Original HTML Button

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, button

```
[Image on top of button][1]
```

I'm having an issue with using an image for a button. The image is sitting on top of the standard button and not replacing it. you can see the original button beneath the image. Not only that, I am not sure if the image itself is actually working as a button.

The situation may be more complicated as I am just starting to learn jQuery, and I'm doing a very good job of confusing myself.

Any help will be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="screen">
                <div class="title">
                  <h1 class="shopper">SHOPPER</h1>
                  <img class="cart" src="images/svg/cart.svg">
              </div>
              <form name="form" id="shopping-form">
                  <div class="add-item">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Add item here" id="addForm">
                    <!-- <button id="add" type="submit">Add</button> -->
                    <input type="submit" id="blue-add">
                    <button id="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
                </div>

            </form>
            <form name="form" id="shopping-list">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

CSS

```
            .green-box {
          background : #95C13D;
          border-style : Solid;
          border-color : #FFFFFF;
          border-width : 1px;
          width : 24px;
          height : 24px;
          border-radius : 4px;
        }
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    if ( $.trim( $('#addForm').val() ) === '' ) {

        return;
    }
    else {
    addItem();
    }
});

//when enter button is pressed
    $("#addForm").keypress(function(i){
        if(i.which==13){
            addItem();
            i.preventDefault();
        }
    });



//add item
    function addItem(){
        var itemToAdd = $("#addForm").val();
        var createItem = '<div class="add-item"><div class="checkcheckcheck"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></div><input type="text" class="item-field" value=" '+itemToAdd + ' "></div>';
        $("#shopping-list").append(createItem);
        $("#addForm").val("");
        $('input.check').change(function(){
        $(this).siblings('itemToAdd').toggleClass('strike');
    });
    }

//remove Item
    $("#remove").click(function(){
        $("input:checked").closest(".add-item").fadeOut(250);
    });

//toggle between line crossed off and on
    $('#shopping-list').on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
        var myInput = $(this).parent().siblings('input[type=text]');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(myInput).css('textDecoration','line-through');
        }
        else{
            $(myInput).css('textDecoration','none');
        }
});


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use `<input type="image" />`. This uses an image as a button.

[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

Comment: Thank you, That has improved matters, the button itself has disappeared, but the text "Submit" is still showing through.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for your help. With a little research based on your answer above, I found that adding - value=" " fixed the problem.

Comment: Just saying it's not a good practice to write thank-you messages as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

```
<input type="image" id="blue-add" name="image" src="http://bit.ly/1R1adHY" width="50">
```

**Option 2:**

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id="blue-add" class="image-button">
<button id="remove" type="button" class="image-button">Remove</button>
```

CSS:

```
.image-button {
    background: url('http://bit.ly/1MpWUex');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    width:100px;
    height:45px;
    font-weight: bold;
     }
  .image-button:hover {
      //you can change image
     }
  .image-button:active {
         //you can change image
     }
```